# How to Redirect to the visualforce page based on the custom picklist selection in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, picklist, pagereference

My visualforce page having custom picklist field with some values, When i select one value that should be redirected to a visualforce page and when i select another value that should be redirected to another page, How to get it?

Comment: Can you share your VF page?

Answer (score 0):

```
Do you want in this way. check it once

public class PicklistController
{
  public Account acc {get; set;}
  public contact con {get; set;}
  public string selectedValue{get;set;}

  public PicklistController()
  {
     acc= new account();
     con = new contact();
     selectedValue='';
  }

  public List<selectoption> getoptions()
  {
   List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
   options.add(new SelectOption('--Select--','--Select--'));
   options.add(new SelectOption('Account','Account'));
   options.add(new SelectOption('Contact','Contact'));
   return options;
  }


  public pagereference save()
  {
    if(selectedValue == 'Account')
    {
    acc= new account();
    }else if(selectedValue == 'Contact')
    {
     con = new contact();
    }
   return null;
 }

 public pagereference AccSave()
 {
   try 
   {
     insert acc;
   }catch(exception e)
   {
   }
   return null;
 }

 public pagereference conSave()
 {
   try 
   {
     insert con;
   }catch(exception e)
   {
   }
   return null;
 }
}

VF page:
<apex:page controller="PicklistController">
 <apex:form >

    Select record Details: <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"></apex:selectOptions>
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!save}" reRender="one,Two" rendered="true" />
     </apex:selectList><br/><br/><br/>

            <apex:pageBlock id="one" title="Account Record Creation">
            <apex:pageblockSection id="one" rendered="{!IF(selectedValue == 'Account', true, false)}">
             <apex:inputField value="{!acc.name}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!acc.type}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.industry}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!acc.accountnumber}"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
           <apex:pageblockButtons >
           <apex:commandButton value="Save Account" action="{!accSave}" rendered="{!IF(selectedValue == 'Account', true, false)}"/>
           </apex:pageblockButtons>

            </apex:pageBlock>

           <apex:pageBlock id="Two" title="Contact record Creation">
            <apex:pageblockSection id="one" rendered="{!IF(selectedValue == 'Contact', true, false)}">
             <apex:inputField value="{!con.firstname}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!con.lastname}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!con.Email}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!con.Phone}"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
           <apex:pageblockButtons >
          <apex:commandButton value="Save Contact" action="{!ConSave}" rendered="{!IF(selectedValue == 'Contact', true, false)}"/>
           </apex:pageblockButtons>

            </apex:pageBlock>     
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you, This is for saving the record,  even this is also helpful to me. But I am looking to pageReference to a page which i can get some records based on the selection of fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet as reference:

------------- vf page--------------

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!picklistvalue}" size="1" >
 <Apex:selectOptions value="{!item}"/>
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!redirect}" />    
 </apex:selectList>
```

--------------- apex controller --------------

```
public class redirectonthebasisonpicklist
 {
public list<selectoption>item{get;set;}
public string picklistvalue{get;set;}
public redirectonthebasisonpicklist()
{
    item=new list<selectoption>();
    item.add(new selectoption('addtocontact','add to contact'));
    item.add(new selectoption('AddtoAssociate','Add to Associate'));
}

public pagereference redirect()
{
     PageReference pageRef= new PageReference('/apex/'+picklistvalue);
    pageRef.setredirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, If i want to redirect to another page based on the another picklist value. how to do the code? It will be very glad.

Answer (score 0):

vf page -

```
    <apex:selectList id="pick2" value="{!redirVal}" size="1" required="true" onchange="redirecttonew();">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}"/>
          </apex:selectList>
<apex:actionFunction name="redirecttonew" action="{!redir}" />
```

controller-

```
public String redirVal {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> getoptionsList(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('None','None'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Redir','Redir'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('NoRedir','NoRedir'));
        return options;
    }
public Pagereference redir(){

        //Pagereference pg = new Pagereference();
        if(redirVal == 'Redir'){
            Pagereference pg = new Pagereference('/apex/SiteRegister');//use your redirect page here
            pg.setredirect(true);
            return pg;
        }
        else
            return null;


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, If i want to redirect to another page based on the another picklist value. how to do the code? It will be very glad.

Comment: Just use another action function in the vf page same manner of `redirecttonew`. Call another new method similar to `redir()` from the controller which contains the code to redirect the desired page.